# How to set header in httppost/ httpget request

Tags: android

i have a web service like " post -H 'Authorization: Token token="2hwhdh443hdhfh43j3jdej3j3"'. how to set this header in httpPost/ get request.

My code is here-

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(MainActivity.baseUrl
                    + "messages");
            request.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type","application/json"));
            request.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization: Token","token= 2hwhdh443hdhfh43j3jdej3j3"));

            response = client.execute(request);
```

but this gives HTML response. Please any one can guide me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try removing "Content-Type" header and modify "Authorization" to -

```
request.addHeader("Authorization","Token token=2hwhdh443hdhfh43j3jdej3j3");
```

Working for me.

Comment: Hi seniors, if I want to use apikey instead of token can I use like this? 
    request.addHeader("Authorization","Token apikey=myapikey");

Comment: @Yithirash You can pass yourapikey as token, request.addHeader("Authorization","Token token=yourapikey"); If you'll change 'token' to 'apikey', It should not work.

Comment: I got this error 

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; in class Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)

Answer (score 0):

You do just silly mistake. Just do this.

Replace this  :-

```
 request.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization: Token","token= 2hwhdh443hdhfh43j3jdej3j3"));
```

To this :-

```
 request.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization: Token","2hwhdh443hdhfh43j3jdej3j3"));
```

Hope this will help. :)